Is a stream of air / jet exhaust low pressure?
Inspired by this answer, is a moving stream of air (Jet exhaust, rocket plume, etc) low pressure?
I’ve always thought that a higher pressure area (say the combustion chamber of a rocket engine) will be high pressure, then the lower pressure atmospheric air will ‘pull’ on the higher pressure combustion chamber gas therefore kind of stretching it out. (I know air never really pulls anything, but it helps to think of it that way)
I found this when doing my own research and in it it says :

When this low-pressure, supersonic jet leaves the nozzle and is confronted with ambient air, the air pressure will compact the jet.

So it seems like this would confirm that a moving jet of air is low pressure, right? Am I missing something?

Do you want to know for subsonic (EPR value) or supersonic velocities? It seems you are mentioning only supersonic engines.

@mins yeah good point. Shockwaves do complicate things, so for simplicity I'll say just below supersonic values / fairly subsonic values.

The pressure in a stream of gas might be above or below ambient pressure.
In the context of the quote, the purpose of a bell aka skirt aka nozzle in a rocket engine is to convert low speed high pressure gas into high speed gas, to increase thrust.  That conversion happens to also reduce the pressure, per Bernoulli.  That reduction might go below ambient, or not.  The one generalization you can make is that the pressure in the exhaust stream is lower than that at the nozzle throat.

Ah okay. So won't the atmosphere do the job of the convergent-divergent nozzle? Not as efficiently maybe, but won't the atmosphere do the same thing?

The "nozzle" converts pressure into speed.  mv of the exhaust is thrust.  Ideally, P at nozzle exit = ambient pressure.  The plume (theoretically) contracts as it cools, but the exchange of exhaust energy to the surrounding air is all after the fact of propulsion.  As long as nozzle pressure is higher, surrounding air pressure cannot do the job of steel.

@RobertDiGiovanni Oh okay, but won't the higher pressure exhaust gas expand, like it  does with a C-D nozzle? (pretend there are 2 cases, one without the C-D nozzle and one with)

You really don't want it to expand, but it's hard to be perfect.  I know standing behind a jet is a bad idea.  Essentially, you have a torrent of high speed air (that entrains ambient air). Your question about the pressure of the stream is interesting, perhaps with pressure as potential energy and the moving stream as kinetic energy.

@RobertDiGiovanni Yeah good points. My guess is that the lower pressure outside atmosphere air will 'stretch' out the higher pressure gas inside the jet engine / rocket engine. I know air doesn't pull anything in that sense, but it helps to think of it that way, as the same effect still happens. That still doesn't mean the stream will be low pressure, as the stretching effect might not be powerful enough at such high pressure (though downstream it might catch up)
